# Editing more than once while reviewing doesn't return one to the review page

Tags: bug, review

While reviewing a given post if one edits the post for the first time and clicks `Save Edits` it is taken back to the review page but if one does this for the second time in the same review, clicking `Save Edit` doesn't take one back to the review page and is instead taken over to the actual post.

Going back one or two pages from the browser brings back the review page.